# Processing LineString from KML File - Coordinates - Bad Rendering in SQL + C#

Tags: coordinates, kml, spatial

I have a simple KML File that contains 1 linestring (the real file has thousands). I am having a problem with the coordinates as google earth draws the single line string as two lines. Whereas my conversion to SQL Server Spatial and in the end C# code will only draw one line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <Document>
    <name>Test.kmz</name>
    <Style id="styleOSR">
      <LineStyle id="lineStyleOSR">
        <color>ff0f00ff</color>
        <width>2</width>
      </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder>
      <name>TEST</name>
      <description>
      </description>
      <Folder>
        <name>TEST</name>
        <Placemark>
          <name>OSR 0038</name>
          <styleUrl>#styleOSR</styleUrl>
          <LineString>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
            <coordinates>
              68.208,86.306,0 70.926,86.203,0 72.984,86.106,0 75.029,85.98900000000002,0 76.32599999999999,85.917,0 78.40300000000001,85.768,0 81.10299999999999,85.639,0 83.143,85.556,0 84.80200000000001,85.5,0 86.80200000000001,85.41800000000001,0 88.486,85.346,0 89.98,85.29600000000001,0 92.313,85.229,0 94.155,85.155,0 95.839,85.102,0 97.27300000000001,85.02800000000001,0 98.568,84.95999999999999,0 99.444,84.911,0 102.918,84.664,0 103.943,84.57800000000002,0 105.302,84.485,0 106.759,84.369,0 107.709,84.295,0 108.939,84.194,0 109.727,84.11,0 110.959,83.965,0 111.974,83.824,0 112.843,83.67400000000002,0 113.723,83.512,0 114.558,83.321,0 115.258,83.151,0 115.793,83.014,0 116.582,82.74,0 117.171,82.539,0 117.755,82.298,0 119.1,82.087,0 119.984,81.595,0 121.004,81.115,0 121.898,80.643,0 122.639,80.206,0 123.408,79.759,0 125.188,78.99,0 125.679,78.133,0 -29.60900000000001,39.993,0 -29.613,40.033,0 -29.58,40.079,0 -29.588,40.106,0
            </coordinates>
          </LineString>
        </Placemark>
      </Folder>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

My problem is that if I load this in google earth it draws two seperate lines on the earth. This is infact what I want to do. You can see two red lines on the picture below, two independant lines!

[image]

But when I process the linestring and then render the line from SQL Server geometry I get one line

So parsing this line of coordinates and putting into SQL Server gives me

[image]

LINESTRING (68.208 86.306, 70.926 86.203, 72.984 86.106, 75.029 85.989000000000019, 76.326 85.917, 78.403 85.768, 81.103 85.639, 83.143 85.556, 84.802 85.5, 86.802 85.418, 88.486 85.346, 89.98 85.296, 92.313 85.229, 94.155 85.155, 95.839 85.102, 97.27300000000001 85.028, 98.568 84.96, 99.444 84.911, 102.918 84.664, 103.943 84.578000000000017, 105.302 84.485, 106.759 84.369, 107.709 84.295, 108.939 84.194, 109.727 84.11, 110.959 83.965, 111.974 83.824, 112.843 83.674000000000021, 113.723 83.512, 114.558 83.321, 115.258 83.151, 115.793 83.014, 116.582 82.74, 117.171 82.539, 117.755 82.298, 119.1 82.087, 119.984 81.595, 121.004 81.115, 121.898 80.643, 122.639 80.206, 123.408 79.759, 125.188 78.99, 125.679 78.133, **-29.609000000000009 39.993, -29.613 40.033, -29.58 40.079, -29.588 40.106**)

The issue is the last 4 coordinates contains these values

-29.609000000000009 39.993, -29.613 40.033, -29.58 40.079, -29.588 40.106

Now Google Earth seems to know that the coordinates are different from each other and ***does not render a single line*** but splits it into two lines.

So my question is how do the same?  Remember I have lots of these and I am wanting to put them on a Google Map as a custom layer - here is my issue - strange lines on my map.

[image]

Here is how google earth actually renders the full KML file.

[image]

If anyone is interested in seeing the original KML file then you can get it from here

[KML File](http://static.canterburyquakelive.co.nz/KML/PlateBoundaries.kml)

This is for my Earthquake Site in New Zealand to show techtonic plates on a map.

http://canterburyquakelive.co.nz

cheers

chris

Answer (score 0):

I only see one artifact if I take the original KML file and [render it using geoxml3 or the google maps v3 API KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/PlateBoundaries_kml.xml)

Easy enough to [fix the kml](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/PlateBoundariesB_kml.xml)

Don't know where the other "strange lines" come from.

Answer (score 0):

google earth is rendering a single line

in your example change the altitude to:

```
<altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
```

with the `relativeToGround`

the missing line segment was going through the globe